# Exceuting function in Shell file from command

Tags: bash, shell

In my shellFile.sh I wrote this function:

```
#!/bin/bash
myFunction(){
echo 1
}
```

I tried to call the function from the command line this way:

```
shellFile.sh
shellFile.sh myFunction
```

After this two lines there is no output and no errors. I apologize if this question is asked before but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call your function inside your script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
myFunction(){
echo 1
}

myFunction
```

If you want to use the function interactively you can source the script, then call the function from the command line.

```
$ source shellFile.sh
$ myFunction
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to be available from the command line, you need to create the function in the current shell, using the dot `.` command, or in Bash its workalike `source`:

```
$ . shellFile.sh
$ myFunction
1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
myFunction(){
  echo 1
}

$1
```

Usage: `./shellFile.sh myFunction`

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks this works but how will you parse arguments if you use $1 outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
myFunction() {
    echo 1
}
myFunction
```